# WooCommerce: Adding a LEFT JOIN to after woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, location, left-join

I'm trying to order my posts by the nearest location to a user.

To solve this issue I created a table called geolocation that contains all latitude(lat) and longditude(long) of by post_id.

In order to sort the posts I used the following hook: woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args

The issue I'm facing Is that I need to join the table I created so I can order the products by lat and long (**ORDER BY (POW((geodata.long-9.9533548),2) + POW((geodata.lat-49.7913044),2)) ASC**)

Using various examples this is what I've came up with - however I'm receiving a 500 Internal error and I'm unsure how to get the join working so I can order by attributes in another table:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_custom_sorting', 99999);

function add_custom_sorting( $options) {
    
    $options['distance'] = 'Nach Standort sortieren';
    return $options;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_sorting_for_distance' );

function custom_sorting_for_distance( $args ) {
    
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && 'distance' === $_GET['orderby'] ) {
        add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_add_join_and_filter', 10, 2);
        
        $lat = sanitize_text_field('49.7913044');
        $lng = sanitize_text_field('9.9533548');
        
        $args['order']    = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
        $args['orderby'] = " (POW((geodata.long-{$lng}),2) + POW((geodata.lat-{$lat}),2)) ";
    }
    
    return $args;
}

function posts_clauses_add_join_and_filter( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $lat = sanitize_text_field('49.7913044');
    $lng = sanitize_text_field('9.9533548');
    
    $clauses['join'] = " LEFT JOIN 4rqJ9_geodata AS geodata ON 4rqJ9_posts.ID = geodata.post_id  ";
            
    $clauses['orderby'] = " (POW((geodata.long-{$lng}),2) + POW((geodata.lat-{$lat}),2)) ";

    return $clauses;

}
```

Has anyone got any idea how to fix this issue? I'm pretty sure that I just need the correct way to join the tables.

This is a SQL Statement that worked fine in the PHPmyADMIN backend and that I am trying to replecate in WooCommerce.

```
SELECT 4rqJ9_posts.* 
FROM 4rqJ9_posts 
INNER JOIN 4rqJ9_postmeta 
    ON ( 4rqJ9_posts.ID = 4rqJ9_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN 4rqJ9_postmeta AS mt1 
    ON ( 4rqJ9_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN 4rqJ9_postmeta AS mt2 
    ON ( 4rqJ9_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN 4rqJ9_geodata AS geodata 
    ON 4rqJ9_posts.ID = geodata.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND 4rqJ9_posts.post_type = 'product' 
    AND ((4rqJ9_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY 4rqJ9_posts.ID 
ORDER BY (POW((geodata.long-9.9533548),2) + POW((geodata.lat-49.7913044),2)) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've tried using the `.=` statement to concatenate the join and orderby values. I've also tried a mock where condition: like `WHERE 1=1` as this is the most slender SQL Statement that worked for me:

```
SELECT 4rqJ9_posts.* FROM 4rqJ9_posts 
LEFT JOIN 4rqJ9_geodata AS geodata ON 4rqJ9_posts.ID = geodata.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 
ORDER BY (POW((geodata.long-9.9533548),2) + POW((geodata.lat-49.7913044),2)) ASC;
```

Comment: not sure if it's an answer to your problem or additions to your question. Which one is it?